# No TXT record found at _acme-challenge for nginx server

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am trying to add a wildcard domain with certbot to nginx server, run the following commands

```
 sudo certbot --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --manual --preferred-challenges dns  --installer nginx -d photoss.co.in -d *.photoss.co.in
```

I got the message

```
 Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.photoss.co.in with the following `value:tXKNeJ2OIWdsDa3Lxnj5fSVXqX5u4ko38ceHd6Pbs`
```

so I entered a txt record on go daddy name server with the above value, when continuing on terminal one more similar message came, so I entered one more txt record without deleting or editing the previous record, but when continuing getting the following error

```
waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain photoss.co.in
Challenge failed for domain photoss.co.in
dns-01 challenge for photoss.co.in
dns-01 challenge for photoss.co.in
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: photoss.co.in
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: No TXT record found at _acme-challenge.photoss.co.in

   Domain: photoss.co.in
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: No TXT record found at _acme-challenge.photoss.co.in

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Comment: There is currently no such TXT record, so you probably did something wrong when adding the record. *"... so I entered a txt record on go daddy name server with the above value ... "* - Impossible to tell what exactly you did in all detail and thus impossible to tell what went wrong when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

When using the DNS-01 challenge, you have to delete the old record, because you cannot have two records with the same hostname and pass the test.

If you fail the test and know you have the record correct, you should set the lowest TTL your DNS server will permit.

This is based only on my own experience of never passing the test without deleting the old record and never passing the test within the TTL of the first test.